# move vue project unexpected error ...mapActions

Tags: node.js, vue.js, vuex

I created a vue project on my local computer then I tried to put it in my work computers (we have a closed server) but then the project does not run properly both the compile (after runing `npm run build`) and uncompile version.
The error I get in the uncompile version is in a file name `app.js` "

> Uncaught SyntaxError unexpected token ...
>
> " the error in line 27239 the line is this
>           ...Object(vuex_WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["mapActions"])(['actionName'])
>
> in the compile version i get two errors of "Uncaught SyntaxError
>   unexpected token ..." in two files chunk-vendors.261c1333.js ,
>   app.195dacfc.js

after remove the reference to the `mapActions` this go for the next file and tell me there is a error syntax in any `vuex` elements `mapState` ...

I tried to reinstall the project , rebring the project from my computer , check the project in my project (works fine).
tried to install on other computers in my companay.
tried to remove this import from the project but the i am getting another reference to error in the project this time on `...mapState(['stateName'])`

```
...Object(vuex_WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["mapActions"])(['actionName'])
...mapState(['stateName']) //show error here in this component
```

I need to find a way to make it posible for vuex to work on my project I think this is the problem.

Comment: have you tried 'yarn install' instead of 'npm install'?

Comment: Delete the `node_modules` folder and then run `npm install`

Comment: @IVOGELOV i can not do that the server is not connected to the internet

Comment: Where are you seeing the errors, in the browser console? Which browser are you running? Do you get the same error (or similar) in other browsers?

Comment: Are you sure that vuex is in your `package.json` and is being imported into your main Vue?

Comment: @skirtle i tried chrome and firefox

Comment: To summarize - you have build a production bundle with Vue-CLI but this bundle works only with the browsers on your laptop and shows errors if you serve the bundle to browsers in your office, is that so ?

Comment: yes , and vux is in the package.json

Comment: I tried other browsers

Comment: I see the errors only in the browser

Comment: I tried browser chrome version 58, edge version 40 and fire fox 54 and on some chrome version 29

Answer (score 0):

So i solved the problem. The issue was that my vue cli version was 2.9.6 and not 3. 
So i updated the vue cli version then created a new project with the new cli.
Then moved all the fukes to the new project and it's worked.